# How to speed up my sql index query in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a select index sql query in Python that I want to run but when I run it it runs really slow it's about 59152 records in the index any reason why it runs so slow? I have a whole file but this part is where it slow down and runs really slow.

```
DbConnect = '********'
myDbConn = pymssql.connect("******","*******", "**************",DbConnect)
cursor = myDbConn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute("""select * from s20data with(INDEX(Storesort)) ;""")
s20data_rows = cursor.fetchall() or []

for s20data_rec in s20data_rows:
    storeid = s20data_rec['storeid']
    ssn = s20data_rec['ssn']
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps just select the columns covered in your index (instead of all columns `*`)? Perhaps use the `explain` function of your db to analyze the query.

Comment: Can you show me a example of what you mean? I need other columns in that index.

Comment: The index isn't being used if you're selecting the entire table. Try selecting just the two columns you need: `select storeid, ssn from s20data`

Comment: I still need to access other columns in the table as well.